# How can I test an internal method inside a component in React?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, enzyme, jestjs

I am trying to test spy a method used inside a React component but I am failing. The component is the below :

```
export class SiderMenu extends PureComponent {

formatter(data, parentPath = '', parentAuthority) {
  return data.map((item) => {
  const result = {
    ...item,
    path: `${parentPath}${item.path}`,
  };
  return result;
});
}
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.menus = this.formatter(props.menuData);
}
render(....)
}
```

I am using enzyme and I want to test that the formatter method has been called:

```
describe.only('SiderMenu.formatter', () => {
  it('Expect to have been called', () => {
  // const spy = jest.spyOn(SiderMenu.prototype, 'formatter');
  const wrapper = shallow(<SiderMenu />);
  const instance = wrapper.instance();
  const method = jest.spyOn(instance, 'formatter');
  expect(method).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
 });
```

I tried also to spy the method using the prototype of the component but I constantly taking the below error

> TypeError: Cannot read property '_isMockFunction' of undefined

This error is created by the 'jest.spyOn(instance, 'formatter');'. Can someone help me out about this ? How can I test that formatter method has been called ?

Comment: you should call the formatter method in componentDidMount()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following works perfectly fine for me:

```
describe.only('SiderMenu.formatter', () => {
  it('Expect to have been called', () => {
    const spy = jest.spyOn(SiderMenu.prototype, 'formatter');
    const wrapper = shallow(<SiderMenu menuData={[{ path: 'foo' }]} />);
    const instance = wrapper.instance();

    expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

Make sure you are passing some `menuData` so that the component doesn't blow up when it tries to map over `undefined`. There are some gotchas with getting this to work (such as using class properties), but you've avoided them here. For more info, see [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/issues/944).

Answer (score 0):

I know nothing about your app but aren't you interested in what `formatter` does or what's the output of it. Why not run an expectation on `this.menus` just after creating an instance of `SiderMenu`.